# best way to integrate with other existing web applications

Tags: asp.net

I have a case that the web application requirement is to integrate with other existing web applications which developed using different platform i.e. silverlight, sharepoint, ASP.NET MVC, and Java.

I am wondering what is the best approach to design this application that can integrate with others. I am thinking to use the HttpWebRequest to integrate by calling other applications' url and does like what we access the other applications via browser. But I am not sure whether this approach is feasible. 
I would like to know if any good enough approach for this kind of integration? thanks.